Power expectation involving a Poisson process
Consider a Poisson process $N_t$ with intensity $\lambda>0$ and let $x$ be a real-valued number. In principle, from the properties of the Poisson distribution, we have:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(x^{N_t})
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}
=e^{-\lambda t}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x\lambda t)^n}{n!}
=e^{\lambda t(x-1)}
\tag{1}
\end{align}
However in in the book from Jeanblanc, Yor & Chesney (2009), Equation (8.2.1), it is stated that the equality $(1)$ only holds when $x>0$. However I am not seeing any problem with the derivation above that might invalidate it whenever $x\leq0$.
For which values of $x$ does equation $(1)$ hold?

The equality holds for all complex $x$, assuming the convention $0^0:=1$. Is it really stated in the book that the equality holds only for $x>0$?

Thank you @IosifPinelis. The authors write: "for every $x>0, t\geq0, \mathbb{E}(x^{N_t})=e^{\lambda t(x-1)}$" (see page 460) so they're not explicitly writing the equality holds only for strictly positive $x$ but that is how I read the condition "$x>0$". This might have been an oversight from their part - or at least it lends itself to confusion.

I don't see any oversight here, and I don't see any problem here either. Of course, authors are not required to present the most general versions of all the claims they make. The problem would arise only if they said "only for $x>0$".

If we do not take $0^0$ to be $1$, then the identity $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n/n!$ fails when $z=0$ because the first term is $0^0/0!.$ And also, what about $N_t$ when $t=0\text{?}$ We want that to be $0,$ which means we want $\Pr(N_0=0)=1,$ but we have that $0^0/0!$ term, which will give us that result only if $0^0=1.$ Moreover, $0^0$ is an empty product and should be $1.$ In some combinatorial problems it appears and clearly has to be $1.\qquad$
